# All of a sudden I have started getting error message from extent report. I am using Test NG and not maven

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I configured extent reports (Selenium - TESTING) in my project and everything was working fine. I had tried to configure Maven but it failed, now extent reports were working fine and suddenly I have started getting below messages in eclipse console,

I tried to clean project, restart the system, update extent jar files, removing Maven related configurations, but nothing worked and still getting the below errors in console and my second iteration is not getting executed properly.

> DEBUG   15341   [freemark] (): Couldn't find template in cache for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
>   DEBUG   15341   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.     findTemplateSource("index_en.ftl"): Not found.
>   DEBUG   15341   [freemark] (): TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("index.ftl"): Found.
>   DEBUG   15341   [freemark] (): Loading template for "index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/Users/a00/Downloads/selenium-java-3.13.0/jar_files(1)       /extentreports-3.1.5.jar!/com/aventstack/extentreports/view/html-report      /index.ftl".

and so on.

Comment: These are not errors, but debug messages from freemarker. You have probably added a logger dependency such as log4j or logback causing this.

Comment: yeah, not sure how to resolve it

Comment: These are not error messages, so nothing to resolve.  If you do not want to see these, use freemarker.log.Logger.selectLoggerLibrary(freemarker.log.Logger.LIBRARY_NONE); to disable freemarker logging.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, adding the library under @Test worked, now there is no trace in the console

Answer (score 2):

Set org.freemarker.loggerLibrary property to none as below

```
System.setProperty("org.freemarker.loggerLibrary", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving to maven as a build tool make sure you have the dependencies for extent reports. Your stack trace is complaining about freemarker. Make sure you have these 3 dependencies in your POM file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi mbn217, As i stated in my question, I tried to move to Maven but due to network security I couldn't , So I am not using Maven and not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: @viki so when you tried maven did you mess with the selenium version or extent reports version at all? my guess its compatability issues between both. If you want to give it a shot . Downgrade your selenium to 3.11 and extent report to 2.41 jar and see how it works. I'm using currently these two jars through maven and it works perfectly.

Comment: I did not mess with any jar file, but I did remove few .html files from the project folder thinking that those are not required, but isn't there any way to come back to the same configuration ? I have added the exact same jar files again, but not sure what template is still missing, what else can be done to bring back prior configuration ?

Comment: I am using selenium 3.14 and Extent report 3.1.5, it worked fine earlier, I removed code for extent report and now it works fine, something is there to do with extent reports, I'll try to clean up and configure extent reports again

Comment: - this was some kind of logging happening, I used the library as mentioned by karthik above and it stopped the same.